# How to view HDR video thumbnails in Windows without dull colors?

Tags: windows, video, thumbnails, hdr, directoryopus

Is there any way to generate brighter thumbnails for HDR videos in windows? Currently I only get the washed out ones. The thumbnails themselves need not be actual HDR, just reqular bright ones. I tried Windows 10, Windows 11, Windows explorer, Directory Opus and Icaros.